# Retrive object [Stored procedures with Dapper]

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

ive tried to search around the web and write some code for the last few hours, with no luck. Either i get some code examples i cant use or the code dosent work, so i guess it's stackoverflow time :)

To make a long story short, my problem is im fairly new to C# and Dapper and would like to know how i retrive a given ID from my database? Let's say i ask for id 1 and voila it returns id 1. Likewise, is it possible to call for lets say a name on the id when i retrive it , like id.name?

I have a ton of other methods i need to write, but i thought i would ask about this and then hopefully be able to write the rest once i see the light.

Thanks in advance.

My stored procedure looks like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAccessHelper

@ID int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.AccessHelper WHERE ID = @ID
END
GO
```

My acceshelper class looks like this:

```
namespace SCAM_MVC.Models.AccessHelper
{

    public class AccessHelper
    {


        public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Plugin { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }


        public AccessHelper(int id, string name, string plugin, string projectName)
        {
            Plugin = plugin;
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
            ProjectName = projectName;
        }

    }
}
```

And my method ive tried looks like this:

```
public void  GetAccessHelper(int id)
        {

            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SQL01; Initial Catalog = SCAM; Integrated Security = True"))
            {

                var accessHelper = sqlCon.Query<AccessHelper>("getAccessHelper", new { id = id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);


            }
        }
```

I know the `id = id`, is wrong, but that's my latest attempt.

Comment: Where is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I can't call id.name for some reason.

Comment: id.name ? where do you want to call it and what is the return you are expecting ?

Comment: I want to be able to, let's say call id.name, so i can print the name of the id.
Thought i would be able to call .name from my acceshelper class.

Comment: You cant call id.name if what you mean by id the id of the accesshelper. you can get the acceshelper object using the id you want and then access its name field !

Comment: Your  GetAccessHelper(int id) method returns nothing because it's void ! what do you need it for if it returns nothing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AccessHelper(int id) method returns nothing because it's void. I suggest you make it return an AccessHelper object like the following :

```
public AccessHelper GetAccessHelper(int id)
    {

        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SQL01; Initial Catalog = SCAM; Integrated Security = True"))
        {

            var accessHelper = sqlCon.Query<AccessHelper>("getAccessHelper", new { id = id }, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);


        }
     return accessHelper ;
    }
```

You can then get the name of your accessHelper instance you need; for example :

```
var ah = this.GetAccessHelper(2); //2 refers to the id you want 
name = ah.Name;
```

Comment: We are getting there, i see what you say, and yes must be me who are tired :) 
However, it says that "The name accessHelper does not exists in the current content" ? Which is strange, since its just above it?

Comment: What did you do exactly ?

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do :)

Comment: If you want the name inside the function itself , you need to write : name = accessHelper.Name.  Do you want the function to return only the name ?